# How to use ELKI for DBSCAN with precomputed distance matrix

Tags: dbscan, elki, precompute

I've a precomputed distance matrix for all the points in my database.
I'm trying to invoke ELKI gui with following command:

```
            /usr/share/java/elki.jar 
            -dbc.in xml_files.1000 
            -dbc.filter FixedDBIDsFilter 
            -dbc.startid 0 
            -algorithm clustering.DBSCAN 
            -algorithm.distancefunction external.FileBasedDoubleDistanceFunction 
            -distance.matrix Distance.txt 
            -dbscan.epsilon 1 
            -dbscan.minpts 10
```

But I keep getting following error message :

Wrong parameter format! Parameter "dbscan.epsilon" requires a distance value, but the distance was not set!

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of ELKI are you using?

This error message usually indicates an issue with the distance *parser* used by the matrix reader.

Since ELKI supports different valued distance functions, DBSCAN cannot parse the epsilon parameter until the actual distance value type is known (which will provide the value parsing function).

Any earlier error message? If you have any earlier error (including missing required parameters), it will prevent DBSCAN from being able to parse the value.

Try setting the epsilon value *last*, and also try the command line. In the MiniGUI, due to the incremental way the parameters are set, these dynamic-typed parameters unfortunately can be flaky. Any patch to improve the handling of such parameters is appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get dbscan running with ELKI.
Turns out I needed:
1. Fix my Java version to openjdk-7.
2. Fix the distance matrix to be only lower triangular instead of a complete n^2 matrix.